# How does AWS Route 53 achieve latency based routing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

AWS Route 53 can provide latency based routing policy (see [latency routing policy from AWS Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html).

But I am wondering how Route 53 knows the latency between my laptop (client) and the server endpoint accurately.

Did AWS publish it's mechanism to provide this feature? Should I trust it with 100% faith or it simply a best-guess based?

Comment: Actually, it's not between your laptop and the server -- it's between your DNS Resolver and the server. So, that's less addresses that AWS needs to know about.

Comment: Actually @JohnRotenstein it's a little more granular than that.  Route 53 uses [edns-client-subnet](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2671) rather than the resolver's address, as of late 2014.

Answer (score 5):

Once you're sending a DNS query, it's too late for the service to try to "triangulate" you, as it were, and actually measure the latency to you.  That isn't what happens.

It's also impractical to locate "you" at all, because it's not "you" that's querying Route 53 -- it's your DNS recursive resolver, usually operated by your ISP or a resolver provided by a recursive DNS provider like Google (8.8.8.8) or OpenDNS.

Route 53 [supports the edns-client-subnet extension](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2671), where the resolver (which must also support it for this part to work) forwards a masked version of your IP address, so that the authoritative server (Route 53) has approximately, but not exactly, your address.  If for example, your IP address were 203.0.113.20, the resolver would send something resembling 203.0.xxx.xxx (an oversimplification, but that's the idea -- adjacent IP addresses, more likely than not, will be geographically proximate). This information is used to come up with an optimal response.  If your resolver doesn't support EDNS, the location of the resolver is used, instead of the potentially more accurate truncated representation of your IP address.

Like all IP-based geolocation, this is not an exact science -- it's a best guess, based on a lookup from a geolocation database that Route 53 maintains, of the global IP address space and the closest AWS region to each block of addresses -- not necessarily physically closest in great circle or air-line distance, but closest based on the topology of the most likely routes for traffic to take, on the Internet.

How did they build that database?  That part isn't documented, of course.

Comment: But then how are route53 geo location records different than latency records? This seems like just geo location not latency based

Comment: @red888 Latency-based is usually geographic in nature, because physical proximity is usually associated with lower latency... but Route 53 Geolocation routing is not necessarily about latency at all.  With Geolocation routing, the mapping is at your discretion and perhaps for political or regulatory or other reasons -- you could, for example, route all of your US viewers to Singapore, except Texas, which you could send to London, then all your Austrailian viewers to São Paulo, and everybody else to Northern Virginia.  Not that you would have a reason to, but you could if desired.

Comment: I guess my confusion was with how latency records actually work. For latency records route53 first determines the user's geo-location, then sees what regional latency records you created, then determines which region is currently serving the lowest latency to that user's location then chooses the record for that region. So this must mean AWS maintains a database or something with latency metrics route53 refers to in _addition_ to geo location for latency routing- right? or maybe its just based on their current BGP topology or something?

Comment: *"determines which region is currently serving the lowest latency to that user's location"* is correct, depending on how we define "currently" -- real-time is impractical.  Interesting reading about how traffic for certain viewers in Singapore was at one time more efficiently routed to CloudFront via Hong Kong than through directly to the Singapore edge, a case where geographic proximity was not the final determinant: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/selecting-service-endpoints-for-reliability-and-performance/

Answer (score 4):

Two videos given by AWS employees which touch on this topic:

- https://youtu.be/PVBC1gb78r8?t=1963
- https://youtu.be/PcoQY82SDHw?t=622

Short summary: they gather latency measurements to AWS regions from users who visit Amazon websites.