# AWS Route 53 Routing Policy: Geolocation Vs Latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

AWS implements latency routing policy based on the ip address of resolver or masked ip address of client. It will help to find the region of low latency.

If both geolocation policy and latency policy are based on the IP address of client, it comes to several questions:

1. what's the difference between them?
2. What's the purpose of Geolocation routing policy?
3. Is geolocation policy used for complying the law of different country?  e.g. GDPR, cookie usage.

   - Europe: GDPR
   - China: data must be stored in China.
4. In which case should I use Geolocation routing policy rather than latency policy?

### Reference

how does AWS Route 53 achieve latency based routing:

- https://youtu.be/PVBC1gb78r8?t=1963
- https://youtu.be/PcoQY82SDHw?t=622

  [How does AWS Route 53 achieve latency based routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668306/how-does-aws-route-53-achieve-latency-based-routing)

Answer (score 10):

Amazon maps-out typical latency between IP addresses and AWS regions. Choose **Latency-based Routing** to have the fastest response.

**Geolocation** maps the IP addresses to geographic locations. This permits rules like "send all users from Côte d'Ivoire to the website in France", so they see a language-specific version. It can redirect by **country, region (eg Oceania) and US state**. Geolocation cares more about the location of users rather than the speed of their connection.

Geolocation pre-dates GDPR. It could be used for **geo-blocking**, but this is typically done in Amazon CloudFront: [Restricting the Geographic Distribution of Your Content - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html)

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on Latency based routing policy?

Comment: @AishwaryaJoshi AWS measure the latency (response time) to many different IP addresses in the world. This can result in faster connections than geo-based routing. For example, there might be a high-speed undersea cable that connects to a distant country faster than a closer country. See: [Latency-based routing - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-latency.html)